# Idle speed connector issues?

Tags: rough-idle

My car idle speed actuator connector has 3 pins. Disconnected the plug from the actuator, and key at on position, and each pins are individually grounded with multimeter, the multimeter reads 12.60 v for the 2 pin, about 1.56 volts each for 1 and 3 pins. Surprise, why pins 2 and 3 are giving voltage reading. Shouldn't they give 0 volts???

Comment: We would need to know the make/model/year/engine of your vehicle to provide a good answer.

Comment: Hyundai i20 1.2 2011 petrol India version

Answer (score 1):

I got this from a 1.6 liter Hyundai manual (we don't have the 1.2 in the USA) but the operation is exactly the same.

[image]

The voltage you are seeing is probably the result of a "pull-up" resistor on the grounding transistors inside the ECU.

Comment: Is this pull up resistor normal??

Comment: @ThangTons  Yes, completely normal.  It biases the transistor so that it does not have a path to ground unless energized.  As a result, it creates a "phantom" voltage on those two signal lines when not active.

Comment: But why the rpm still at 650 from normal 850 after having cleaned the TB unit, ISCV??? Also, I try resetting the computer memory by disconnecting the battery and reconnect after 15 minutes. Still then, no change. Still 650!!! Please kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: I would check and clean the ISCV and make sure the Throttle Position Sensor (TPS) is adjusted correctly.

Comment: Yes, have done all cleaning including iscv, TB unit etc etc... still 650 rpm

Comment: Also check for plug HT wires resistance... found out that plug 4 has very high resistance over 12.5 kohm as against the recommended 1.0 kohm..the remaining 3 HT cables are ok. Change the plug 4 and still no results to restore to 850 rpm!!!! Please kindly help... I'm totally helpless now...